# Ember Promise Many Array

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, contentful

I'm trying to get assets from a Contentful backend. I have a picture gallery and would like to loop through all assets in a given field (Contentful has an asset field that allows multiple images).

Currently I'm getting:

```
<DS.PromiseManyArray:ember527>
```

when trying to get the images in my template and in Ember Data.

Still a bit new to the Contentful thing and having trouble iterating through this..

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: Made this easier to work with by making async: false in the model, but curious to see better, different ways to work with Promise data..